# Launch Microsoft Edge Chromium browser using selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to launch Microsoft Edge Chromium browser using selenium.
Microsoft Edge chromium Version: Version 79.0.309.65 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Downloading driver file from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/

Using this code to for the same but it is giving unreachable browser Exception and not working.

```
1.System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge Beta\\Application\\msedgedriver.exe");
EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
BROWSER=properties.getProperty("BrowserName");
options.setCapability(BROWSER, false);
//DesiredCapabilities  m_capability = DesiredCapabilities.edge();
driver= new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), options);
2.DesiredCapabilities  m_capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
BROWSER=properties.getProperty("BrowserName");`enter code here`
m_capability.setCapability( BROWSER, "chrome" );
driver = new ChromeDriver();
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                   "C:\\edgedriver_win64-1\\msedgedriver.exe");
```

Comment: I am very curious if the new Edge-Chromium (january 15, 2020 or later) is able to be executed headless.   Does anyone know?   If so, i want to make a docker image to run it.

Answer (score 0):

It is looking like compatibility issue. You can upgrade or downgrade your `msedgedriver` driver version to make it work.

I will recommend you to use `WebDriverManager`

> WebDriverManager allows to automate the management of the binary
>   drivers (e.g. chromedriver, geckodriver, etc.) required by Selenium
>   WebDriver.

**maven dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Once we have included this dependency, you can let WebDriverManager to manage the WebDriver binaries for you. Now you can set driver instance for Edge.

```
public class EdgeDevTest {

    private WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setupClass() {
        WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();
    }

    @Before
    public void setupTest() {
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.setBinary(
                "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge Dev\\Application\\msedge.exe");
        EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions().merge(chromeOptions);
        driver = new EdgeDriver(edgeOptions);
    }

    @After
    public void teardown() {
        if (driver != null) {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide a link from which you have downloaded the driver file for the Edge Chromium browser..?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium

Comment: If you will use webDriverManager then you don’t need to download it, webdriverManager will download compatible driver version  itself.

Comment: Thanks for response Muzzamil.

Comment: I am using code which you have provided bug giving error to this lines  new EdgeOptions().merge(chromeOptions);
        driver = new EdgeDriver(edgeOptions);

Comment: What is the error? Try to keep latest driver and other dependencies

Comment: Do you have added dependency of webdriverManager?

Comment: Yes i have added webdriverManager dependency.

Comment: What is the Error ?

Comment: Hi getting error for this line new EdgeOptions().merge(chromeOptions);

Comment: Getting this error as Type mismatch: can't convert from MutableCapabilities to EdgeOption for line new EdgeOptions().merge(chromeOptions);

Comment: Using code like this : else if(properties_browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Edge"))
   {
     ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
           chromeOptions.setBinary(
                   "msedgedriver.exe");
           EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions().merge(chromeOptions);
           driver = new EdgeDriver(edgeOptions);
   }

Answer (score 0):

```
public void testservice(){  
    EdgeOptions opt= new EdgeOptions();
    opt.setHeadless();
    WebDriver driver= new EdgeDriver(opt);

}
```